# ErroR menu tab xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have menu with several item so it is not showing all, how to solve?

IMAGEM[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27eoT.png)

Comment: app:tabMode="fixed" needs to be changed to app:tabMode="scrollable" in the xamarin.android -> resources -> layout -> tabbar.axml

Comment: I'm not using xaml, I'm doing it by C#

Comment: Can you post the code or part of the code which you've implemented

Comment: Follow the code [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M_Zw3oLz7pkB4T0x-9nMN17ouLNBWHu4Qj9YycKQZZ8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You're using tabs, then what i have suggested should work, its not XAML what am talking about. For each Xamarin.Forms project there should be a specific platform project in your case go to CronoFitness.Droid project look for Resources Folder -> Layout Folder -> Tabbar.axml file open it and edit the app:tabMode="fixed" to app:tabMode="scrollable"

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong, I did what I say and it worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If they are inside the grid layout, the row properties, height and width are very important.

"*" If used, the area remaining from other areas is covered.
"Auto" if is used, it refers to the cover as the text inside.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition> 
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

If you use other page layouts, you can add them to the grid layout. I hope it works for you.

[image]